# What's the fastest way to loop through a list and create a single string?

Tags: python, nested-lists

For example:

```
list = [{"title_url": "joe_white", "id": 1, "title": "Joe White"},
        {"title_url": "peter_black", "id": 2, "title": "Peter Black"}]
```

How can I efficiently loop through this to create:

```
Joe White, Peter Black
<a href="/u/joe_white">Joe White</a>,<a href="/u/peter_black">Peter Black</a>
```

Thank you.

Comment: And please remember to NEVER use the name "list" for a variable!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first is pretty simple:

```
', '.join(item['title'] for item in list)
```

The second requires something more complicated, but is essentially the same:

```
','.join('<a href="/u/%(title_url)s">%(title)s</a>' % item for item in list)
```

Both use [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), which are similar to list comprehensions without the need for an extra list creation

Comment: Reusing the dictionary is a good idea. The same with the new str.format: ','.join('<a href="/u/{title_url}">{title}</a>'.format(**item) for item in list)

Comment: @tokland, @Michael: added benchmarks for `str.format` to my answer, 20-25% slower than `str % `. Also in both cases, using `'%s' % ()`  for the second one makes the total about 25% faster than `'%()s' % {}`.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some speed comparisons to check these two methods that you've been given.

First, we create the list of 100000 entries; boring and perhaps not a genuine sample due to having shorter strings, but I'm not worried about that now.

```
>>> items = [{"title_url": "abc", "id": i, "title": "def"} for i in xrange(100000)]
```

First, Michael Mrozek's answer:

```
>>> def michael():
...     ', '.join(item['title'] for item in items)
...     ','.join('<a href="/u/%(title_url)s">%(title)s</a>' % item for item in items)
...
```

Nice and simple. Then systempuntoout's answer (note that at this stage I'm just comparing the iteration performance, and so I've switched the %s and tuple formatting for %()s dict formatting; I'll time the other method later):

```
>>> def systempuntoout():
...     titles = []
...     urls = []
...     for item in items:
...             titles.append(item['title'])
...             urls.append('<a href="/u/%(title_url)s">%(title)s</a>' % item)
...     ', '.join(titles)
...     ','.join(urls)
...
```

Very well. Now to time them:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(michael, number=100)
9.6959049701690674
>>> timeit.timeit(systempuntoout, number=100)
11.306489944458008
```

Summary: don't worry about going over the list twice, combined with generator comprehension it's less expensive than the overhead of list.append; Michael's solution is about 15% faster on 100000 entries.

Secondly, there's whether you should use `'%(...)s' % dict()` or `'%s' % tuple()`. Taking Michael's answer as the faster and simpler of the two, here's `michael2`:

```
>>> def michael2():
...     ', '.join(item['title'] for item in items)
...     ','.join('<a href="/u/%s">%s</a>' % (item['title_url'], item['title']) for item in items)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(michael2, number=100)
7.8054699897766113
```

And so we come to the clear conclusion here that the string formatting is faster with a tuple than a dict - almost 25% faster. So if performance is an issue and you're dealing with large quantities of data, use this method `michael2`.

*And if you want to see something really scary, take systempuntoout's original answer with class intact:*

```
>>> def systempuntoout0():
...     class node():
...             titles = []
...             urls = []
...             def add_name(self, a_title):
...                     self.titles.append(a_title)
...             def add_link(self, a_title_url, a_title):
...                     self.urls.append('<a href="/u/%s">%s</a>' % (a_title_url, a_title))
...     node = node()
...     for entry in items:
...             node.add_name(entry["title"])
...             node.add_link(entry["title_url"], entry["title"])
...     ', '.join(node.titles)
...     ','.join(node.urls)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(systempuntoout0, number=100)
15.253098011016846
```

A shade under twice as slow as `michael2`.

---

One final addition, to benchmark `str.format` as introduced in Python 2.6, "the future of string formatting" (though I still don't understand why, I like my `%`, thank you very much; especially as it's faster).

```
>>> def michael_format():
...     ', '.join(item['title'] for item in items)
...     ','.join('<a href="/u/{title_url}">{title}</a>'.format(**item) for item in items)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(michael_format, number=100)
11.809207916259766
>>> def michael2_format():
...     ', '.join(item['title'] for item in items)
...     ','.join('<a href="/u/{0}">{1}</a>'.format(item['title_url'], item['title']) for item in items)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(michael2_format, number=100)
9.8876869678497314
```

11.81 instead of 9.70, 9.89 instead of 7.81 - it's 20-25% slower (consider also that it's only the second expression in the function which uses it, as well.

Comment: Nice. I even used normal string formatting originally, and then I changed it; I'm surprised there's so much of a difference in speed

Comment: @Michael: also bear in mind that these 25% figures of mine are fairly useless as there's the "constant overhead" of `', '.join(item['title'] for item in items)`. They should be higher - maybe around 40%.

Comment: "twice as slow" is a ridiculous statement. Testing the class declaration and object creation is a nonsense :), and you can make my systempuntoout0 faster storing item['title'] in a tmp variable avoiding the double access (though slower than Michael solution)! Good job and lesson learned, anyway try to avoid that subtle arrogant tone next time, it's not a great thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
class node():
    titles = []
    urls = []
    def add_name(self, a_title):
        self.titles.append(a_title)
    def add_url(self, a_title_url, a_title):    
        self.urls.append('<a href="/u/%s">%s</a>' % (a_title_url, a_title))

node = node()
for entry in list:
    node.add_name(entry["title"])
    node.add_url(entry["title_url"],entry["title"])

print ','.join(node.titles)
print ','.join(node.urls)
```

Comment: Congrats, you just wrote ten lines too much. (And it's trivial to turn Michael Mrozek's version into a very long oneliner that builds both strings at once)

Comment: @delnan I'm doing just one iteration (except for the two join), I would be curious to test it for 100000 entries.What do you think?

Comment: `(item['title'], '*html template*' % item) for item in list` is one iteration as well ;) (That's what I meant by "oneliner" - well, my fault)

Comment: @delnan yep, anyway Michael is doing two iterations.

Comment: @systempuntoout: even stripped of the class system (why on earth did you do that? It makes it messier and slower), yours is slower. Figures coming.

Comment: @Chris I don't know :) (probably my latent Java background), I just thought to do it in one iteration. I'm interested to see the figures, feel free to edit my answer if you want.

Comment: @systempuntoout: Java background? Is that why you felt compelled to put it in a class? Don't. Answer added with figures; twice as slow as an optimisation of Michael's answer.